# GFCI outlets in kitchen

Tags: receptacle, kitchens

I was wondering if i could have one outlet control all counter outlets? I need to replace some and trying to do this cheaper.

I'm buying a property and trying to get it up to code.

Comment: Have you mapped out the breaker panel as to which outlets are on which circuits yet?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your kitchen is wired. If one breaker controls all your kitchen counter outlets, you can replace the "first" outlet with a GFCI and protect the rest of them from it. If you have two or more breakers for the kitchen counter   outlets then the "first" outlet on each circuit needs to be a GFIC. you could also change the breakers for your kitchen outlets to GFCI breakers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any GFCI device can protect down line loads.

GFCI receptacles are no exception.

This requires attaching the downline hot and neutral to the LOAD terminals.  This is the ONLY reason to use these terminals. Don't use them for anything else.

Outlets thus protected must get a sticker"GFCI Protected" or they will fail inspection.

Remember not to put the fridge on GFCI if you can avoid it!

Comment: There is no code exception to not putting the fridge on a GFCI, at least in the current cycle.  In fact everything in the kitchen regardless if it is on the counter or not is supposed to be DFCI protected, not only GFCI

Comment: @kris I have not heard of AHJs requiring full boat retrofit to NEC'17 for a flip.  They require kitchen GFCI because it's easy and has a lot of bang for the buck.

Comment: @Kris -- as of 2017, for resi kitchens, it's still only the countertop receptacles that require GFCI protection.

Comment: Kitchen outlets ( including wall and counter top outlets ) have to be on Arc Fault protection too -210.12(A).  So, with that in mind, if you want to just put the counter top outlets on a Dual function Device "DFCI outlet/breaker", and the rest on a AFCI outlet/breaker go for it.